# .htaccess: Block all countries except for one country

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to block all country access except for one using .htaccess.

What I have right now is

```
RewriteEngine on
<Directory nameOfDirectory>
Order Allow, Deny
Allow IP range 1
Allow IP range 2
</Directory>
```

I keep getting Internal Server Errors. What I am doing wrong? Note that country in question actually has over 500 IP ranges.

Of course if there is a better way to do this besides .htaccess, I am all ears.

Update: Apache error log

```
[Tue Mar 15 06:29:37.308444 2016] [core:alert] [pid 14435] [client xxx.xxx.6.2:59534] /var/www/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
```

Comment: Why not try [this generator](http://incredibill.me/htaccess-block-country-ips) to create the addresses and .htaccess file for you?

Comment: @egg I tried that site before. I am still getting an 'internal server error' plus I want to block a specific directory which that site doesn't provide the syntax for.

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, but how about denying first and adding the `Deny from all`; something like this:

```
<Directory "nameOfDirectory">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.0.1
    Allow from 192.168.0.2
    Allow from 10.0.0.1
    Allow from 10.0.0.2
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Your `error.log` tells you that you don't have permission to use `<Directory>`. So you can either allow it (with `AllowOverride Authconfig FileInfo Options` in your apache config for the directory) or just drop a `htaccess` file inside the directory to protect and remove the `<directory>` tags.

This will work in the directory you want to protect:

```
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.0.1
    Allow from 192.168.0.2
    Allow from 10.0.0.1
    Allow from 10.0.0.2
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Tried that. The problem is that it's throwing a 'server error' as if there is a problem with the syntax or something.

Comment: Updated post with error log. Seems like I can't have .htaccess in /var/www?

Comment: It means you can't have <Directory> in your htaccess; either allow this or remove the `Directory` tags and drop this file in the directory to protect (updated answer).

Comment: Still getting an 'internal server error.' I actually removed everything except for the 'RewriteEngine on' 'order,allow,deny' 'deny all' ...and put it in that specific folder.

Comment: The [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) option in your apache config doesn't allow you to use `Order` or `Deny` either, which stops you in your tracks. You'll need to change this to `AllowOverride Authconfig FileInfo Options` for your `Directory` or VHost.

Comment: This is what I have in apache2.conf:

<Directory /var/www>
        Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride Authconfig FileInfo Options
</Directory> getting an internal error still

Comment: I am getting an error when restarting Apache `The apache2 configtest failed, so we are trying to kill it manually. This is almost certainly suboptimal, so please make sure your system is working as you'd expect now!`